# Azure devops query team projects

Tags: azure-devops

I want a query that looks at all team projects whose names begin with "customer". Is that possible or do I have to list them all?

Additionally, is there a way to filter all queries on top of an Azure DevOps dashboard by a common variable?"

I have tried a query but the drop-down for the filter is not available.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible or do I have to list them all?

You have to list them all. You may use `or` in groups:

[image]

or `in` for the Team Project field:

[image]